# Ext JS - Panel not resizing on window resize

Tags: extjs4.2

I have used the `EventManager.onWindowResize` event to handle window resize to adjust my layout. It works fine only for the Viewport. I want my inner commponents, viz. Grids and Panels to be adjusted accordingly. Is there a way to achieve this? I have written custom code to handle the resize individually for every component. Which works fine for my grids and panels. But, the panel headers don't resize! They are just stuck there.

My layout is as follows:

```
[Viewport]
    [Form Panel]
        [Panel containing Grid] [Panel containing Grid]
    [/Form Panel]
[/Viewport]
```

The Grids resize but not the Panel which contains the Grid. Moreover, I've used anchor, but my percent widths are ignored.

Any default way to implement resize?

Comment: The resize is handled automatically. Use `EventManager.onWindowResize` only if you want to override the default behavior, which is always resize everything automatically.

Comment: Strange! My site doesn't resize if I change the browser size by dragging the corners. That is why I had to write the code. Any options that I need to include so that my resize works across the site?

Comment: Create a default app using `sencha app build`. It will work on it. Then compare to your app what's different.

Comment: it could be that an anchor layout won't resize, if you want to place 2 grids side by side, try the column layout.

Comment: Anchor layout worked! Experimented a bit with the options and finally got there. The only place where I required JS was resizing the Viewport, everything else worked with anchors. Thanks!

Comment: @Jandalf The column layout requires me to use pixel width, which doesn't resize well. And both of my neighbour grids are contained in 2 panel parents.

Comment: you can set the width to 0.5 for example, but good its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Used `anchor` layout everywhere. The Viewport required some JS code, but `anchor` solved my problem. Thanks everyone for their inputs.